# How to implement readLine()!!.toIntArray() on Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, readline

I would like to implement a function or some way **to store an array sequentially from a console**. Something like this: `readLine()!!.toIntArray()`

> Would it be convenient to use a loop for this or could it be avoided?

And then you can access them using the index of the array.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    myFunction()
}
```

**A:**

```
fun myFunction() {
    println(" . First number: ")
    val num1:Float = readLine()!!.toFloat()
    println(" . Second number: ")
    val num2:Float = readLine()!!.toFloat()
    println(" . Third number: ")
    val num3:Float = readLine()!!.toFloat()
    println(" . Fourth number: ")
    val num4:Float = readLine()!!.toFloat()

    val result:Float = (num1+num2) + (num3*num4)
    print("The result is: $result")
}
```

**B:**

```
fun myFunction() {
    println("Enter four numbers ...")
//    val numbers:IntArray = intArrayOf(45, 22, 10, 13)
    val numbers:IntArray = readLine()!!.toIntArray()   //HERE: toIntArray() isn't defined

    val result:Int = (numbers[0]+numbers[1]) + (numbers[2]*numbers[3])
    print("The result is: $result")
}
```

When defining the Array I will have to indicate the amount of values that I want to be read from the console, that is, the size of the Array.

> Or is there another way to stop reading data in the console?

In short, I want to move from block A to the idea of block B.

### SOLUTION

```
println("Enter four numbers ...")
val numbers = readLine()!!.split(" ").map { it.toInt() }

val result:Int = (numbers[0]+numbers[1]) + (numbers[2]*numbers[3])
print("The result is: $result")
```

Comment: `val numbers = readLine().split(" ").map { it.toFloat() }` or `it.toInt()`

Comment: I changed readLine() by readLine()!!. Excellent, when I have a reputation, I vote you.

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop. It can be done with `map`:

```
val numbers = readLine()!!.split(" ").map { it.toInt() }
```

Comment: How do we do if if the input are not 1 2 5 6 but 1256 and i want to have an array(1,2,3,5,6)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read the numbers from separate lines like in your examples:

```
val list = List(4) { readline()!!.toFloat() }
```

The same can be done with arrays, but it is recommended to use lists in Kotlin

Comment: Why lists and not arrays?

Comment: Because Lists have almost the same performance as arrays, but much nicer API - they implement Iterable<T>, thus getting a lot of useful functionality